# Determine domain of $f(x,y)$ and describe $x$ and $y$

Tags: functional-analysis

I was given an exercise to find the domain of the given function :

$$f(x,y) = \frac{ln(x^2+y^2-1)}{\sqrt{x}}+ \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{4-x^2-4y}}$$

[Scan of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayenu.jpg)

I solved it graphically but my professor told me that indeed it is correct but I did not describe $x$ and $y$ in the following maner (quoting my professor) " $<x<$ and $<y<$ ". How could this be done? I am clueless at this point.

Comment: Does he want some sort of condition for that region in the plane? Because that would be what you wrote in the domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y<-x^2/4+1,y\geq0,x>0,x^2+y^2>1\}$ is the domain you want.

Comment: I agree, this also describes the region in the plane

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer and explanation! Now it's crystal clear.